# How to open Doc or Pdf extension file inside app

Tags: android, file, doc

I am working on a app where there is need to open (.xls/.xlsx/.doc/.docx/.pdf) extension inside the app . Please tell me is this feasible? . How we can open these all indie app?

Comment: [jOpenDocument](http://www.jopendocument.org/)

Comment: Yes you can open them inside app by reading content using libraries that are available like jxl.jar etc. Google to get resources for each. And BTW SO is not place for opinions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Please try some code and ask for help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PDF files, try MuPDF library. Check licence agreement before you start. Also check

- [Android PDFView](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview)
- [APV library](https://code.google.com/p/apv/source/checkout)

To open doc file, there are multiple approaches. Check bellow links

- [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)
- [Google Docs viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to open a file that is present in SDCard

```
/* Browses the SD Card using Intent Action Get Content */
    private void browseFileFromSDCard() {
        TLog.i(LOG, "Browse File From SD Card");
        Intent selectFile;
        Intent intent;
        selectFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        selectFile.setType("file/*");
        intent = Intent.createChooser(selectFile, "Select a file");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            TLog.w(LOG, "Activity Not found Exception");
            String fileManagerNotFoundMessage = getResources().getString(R.string.file_manger_not_found_message);
            Toast.makeText(this, fileManagerNotFoundMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: the user want to open the files inside app, not use external app i.e he wants a pdf/xls/doc reader in app and not use some other pdf/doc reader. Your answer is not solution for ques.